# Reliance Broadband Netconnect is not connecting due to error 718

Tags: internet-connection, broadband

When I tried to connect Reliance Netconnect I am getting error 718 which is telling that the connection was terminated because the remote computer did not respond in a timely manner. I Googled it and found one solution from [reliance net connect](http://www.reliancenetconnect.co.in/trouble-shooting.html#718) that I need to uninstall and re install it. I tried to uninstall the software and re installed it but still its not working. Help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Reliance Datacard Number as your username and password or you should call Reliance Customer care and they will help you to get a new username and password. By using that username and password you can access Internet through your Reliance Netconnect.